# Recursive list in Python BUG

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was making an HTML parser and unexpectedly got the following bug: for some reason, the head tag (in this case) in children contains the same tag ad infinitum. I don’t understand what this could be connected with, chatgpt didn’t help, and I don’t know what to do anymore.
Code:

```py
class HTMLTag:
    def __init__(self, name, attrs=[], children=[]):
        self.name = name
        self.attrs = attrs
        self.children = children
        self.closed = False
        self.data = []

    def addChild(self, child):
        if isinstance(child, HTMLTag) and child not in self.children:
            self.children.append(child)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"<{self.name}> {', '.join(str(child) for child in self.children)}"

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<{self.name}>"

html = HTMLTag("html")
head = HTMLTag("head")

print(html.children,
      head.children)

html.addChild(head)

print(html.children,
      head.children)
```

Result:

```
[] []
[<head>] [<head>]
```

Most likely the problem is in addChild, but the code is correct